# logman command at startup requires elevation

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, uac, logman

I am trying to setup Performance Counters on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server and have successfully setup the counters. The problem is that I need to manually start the counters each time the server is restarted.

I found a neat trick to add the "logman" command to the registry to start the counters automatically, however, this command does not work because the command requires elevation.

Is there a way to elevate this command? Please note that as I have the command in the registry, I am unable to just simply run the CMD program as Administrator. I am happy to consider any suggestions or work arounds, so long as they are simple and work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you could use [srvany.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657) from the windows 2003 server resource kit, and launch Logman as a service.

There are several ways you might accomplish this - start the service with credentials, or use logman command line credentials

Comment: command line credentials are not ideal as this would mean having elevated credentials in clear text in the registry. Running as a service may work, though I feel this is over complicating it. You did give me an idea though, I may be able to run this as a Scheduled Task that runs on Startup.

Comment: Right. Your choice - launch the service with credentials (which are protected by windows), or use Logman's command line, which is not protected by windows.  Although you could set Logman's launch parameters in a vb script and encode it, or compile a windows batch file, which would mask user and password.